# How to modify an Amazon ECS Cluster and use custom UserData to mount EFS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

Need to mount EFS drive on ECS Cluster automatically on launch of container instances. Is it possible with Clusters generated with the Wizard or do I need to create an AutoScaling group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ECS Cluster is a logical grouping of hosts and does not cause any hosts to be provisioned. You probably want an autoscale group for that, in which case you'd probably configure the host via userdata / cloud-init to mount the EFS volume at bootup.

Comment: Yes, exactly, an AutoScale group is created by the wizard too I missed that earlier, and figured out it's possible to go in and modify that, so updated with my modified Launch Configuration and it works perfectly.